# Remove / Clear Error message tool tips on Cancel button click

Tags: validation, apache-flex, popup

I have referred this for creating error message tool tips, to be displayed continuously unless the error is resolved by the user. :: http://aralbalkan.com/1125 .....................

But, this is being applied to a pop-up window visualized as a pop-up form.

When the user clicks 'CANCEL' button, I want the error message tooltips if present to be cleared off from the screen. The message tool tips remains on the screen even if the CANCEL button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tooltips created are not linked to the dialog pop-up directly - i.e. they're not created as child widgets of the pop-up.

To work around this you hook into the cancel button with an on-click hander, and have the handler loop through all elements in the errorMessageToolTips dictionary, hiding each one.

Depending on your code structure, to avoid problems later on you may want to make the errorMessageToolTips dictionary specific to the pop-up and not a global array.

Comment: Ok....What I have done is created a an array. Value as the target is pushed into the array whenever error occurs. This keeps a track of all the targets where tool-tip is visible. When cancel clicked, I use a for loop and make all tooltips of targets in the array invisible. This works. But, I am not sure if this is an optimal way of doing that, since am using an array. Is there no direct command or function for doing this ?

Comment: Given the custom nature of what you're doing, I don't believe so.